# Get all data left table with condition on the right table (ms sql)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

colA   colB --------------------------------tab_1
1 AA
2 BB
3 CC
4 DD
5 EE

colA   colC-------------------------------tab_2
1 XX
2 YY
3 ZZ

output must (tab_2.colC != ZZ)

colA colB colC
1    AA    XX
2    BB    YY
4    DD    NULL
5    EE    NULL

i tried it with left join but it will return all 5 records

e.g :

`select tab_1.colA, tab_1.colB, tab_2.colC`
`from tab_1`
`left join tab_2 on tab_1.colA = tab_2.colA and tab_2.colC != 'ZZ'`

I really appreciate if someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
T1.colA, T1.colB, T2.olC
FROM tab_1 T1
  LEFT JOIN tab_2 T2
    ON T1.colA = T2.colA
WHERE T2.colC != 'ZZ'
   OR T2.colC IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer here taking `NULL` into account, all others are basically doing an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.ColC
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ColA = b.ColA
WHERE   b.colC <> 'zz' OR b.ColC IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1827/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.colA, t1.colB, t2.colC
FROM tab_1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab_2 t2
ON tab_1.colA = tab_2.colA
WHERE t2.ColC <> 'ZZ' OR t2.ColC IS NULL
```